# Office UI Fabric react mergeStyles :hover selector

Tags: javascript, office-ui-fabric

I'm using the fantastic office UI fabric package and I am getting stumped on how to get the `:hover` pseudo selector working as I want.

Basically what I would like to do is this:

```
export const getMainNavClassNames = (): IMainNavClassNames => mergeStyleSets({
    nav: {
        selectors: {
            '& .ms-Nav-compositeLink:hover': {
                background: theme.palette.themeDark
            }
        }
    }
});
```

However the :hover selector does not work if there is no space between the class.  The following **will** work, but it's selecting the child of .ms-Nav-compositeLink which is not what I want.

```
export const getMainNavClassNames = (): IMainNavClassNames => mergeStyleSets({
    nav: {
        selectors: {
            '& .ms-Nav-compositeLink :hover': {
                background: theme.palette.themeDark
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I've tried every permutation I can think of based on the [documentation](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/tree/master/packages/merge-styles).

Comment: Hi Daniel, could you provide a codepen with what you are struggling with so that I can help you with the `hover` selector? Here is a starter for you: https://codepen.io/vitalius1/pen/oJRKxB

Comment: Thanks Vitalie, it turns out that using the psuedo selectors do work as expected eg .className:hover etc.  As the components have several styles to target, i needed to be a bit more precise on the className I was targeting.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the selector does work as expected, however I needed to be more aware of the class css hierarchy using the devtools to target the class appropriately.  It helps to look closely at the classNames generated by mergeStyle to determine which style to target.